# Is $\pi$ in the infinite set $ \{ 3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, ...\} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, decimal-expansion

Does $\pi$ exist in the following infinite set. Apologies for lack of set notation, and i'm hoping its not necessary to help me understand the nature of infinite decimal expansion.

I know sets are unordered but for simplicity and intuition I will show the set being generated in increasing size.

$$ \{ 3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, ...\} $$

The definition of the set is 'An infinite set containing $\pi$'s decimal representation from 0 to $\infty$ significant figures.'

My (very limited!) intuition based on the notion of infinity and decimal expansion is that this set *cannot* contain $\pi$.

However, intuition based on how infinite sequences rather than sets can converge hints the opposite. Is it possible that a sequence generated this way will converge towards $\pi$ and an infinite set generated this way will never contain $\pi$?

If this question is daft and can be answered with a simple axiom relating to irrational numbers,  please be kind, i'm more hobbyist than math student. Thanks.

Comment: Every entry has a terminating decimal expansion, hence $\pi$ is not in the list.

Comment: You are correct. $\pi$ is not in this set since it only contains finite decimal expansions.

Comment: It indeed does not contains $\pi$, even if you use sequences, it does not contains $\pi$. The *limit* of the sequence will be $\pi$, but no stage inside the sequence is $\pi$ itself. Similarly for sets, we can get as close as we want to $\pi$, in the sense that for each $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{3, 3.1, 3.14...\}\cap (\pi-\epsilon, \pi+\epsilon)$ contains infinitely many elements, but non of those elements is $\pi$ itself

Comment: "*from 0 to $\infty$ significant figures*" This is not very clear.  Perhaps you mean "*any finite number of significant figures.*"  If you mean for the set to contain *only* those rational approximations to $\pi$ taken to a finite number of significant figures, then no $\pi$ does not appear in your set (*though it is a limit point*).  If you mean by "$\infty$ significant figures" that not only you do include not only those with finite cutoff points but *also* an element "*with infinitely many significant figures matching $\pi$*" then yes, $\pi$ is an element.

Comment: If you did mean the second however, then $\{3,3.1,3.14,3.141,\dots\}$ is not a very good representation of the set and it would have been better written as $\{\pi,3,3.1,3.14,3.141,\dots\}$.  As to whether or not $\pi$ is an element of the sequence "$3,3.1,3.14,3.141,\dots$" it is not, though it is the *limit* of the sequence.  The limit of a sequence does not need to be an element of the sequence itself.

Comment: $\infty$ is by the way not a number, so we should avoid to speak of a number with "$\infty$ many significant figures" (I assume this means "digits"). I am pretty sure you meant it as a sequence giving the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ (including the $3$ before the comma) correctly. And then , $\pi$ is not in the list although it has infinite many entries.

Comment: What you've demonstrated is that a set can have a *limit point* that is not in the set. Your set has one limit point, $\pi,$ and that limit point is not a member of the set.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the reply, and your description 'n digits of pi' I think is a much better way of describing the set.

Comment: @JMoravitz Apologies for not being clear and thanks for taking the time to respond. The idea of a limit point that does not have to be a member is very clear and helpful, thanks.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All the numbers in your sequence are decimal numbers, which are a subset of the rational numbers. But $\pi$ is not a rational number, therefore it is not a member of this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

First off, great question!

---

To answer your question, no, $\pi$ will not be present in that infinite set, because all numbers in it are numbers with terminating decimals (in other words, they are rational numbers). However, $\pi$ is not rational, so it cannot be in the set.

---

To say the same thing in another manner, assume for the sake of contradiction that $\pi$ exists in that set. We do know that $\pi$ has infinite digits and that it is not rational. But all elements of that infinite set are rational (because they have terminating decimals), and hence we have a contradiction.

---

I hope this helped!
If you have any questions regarding my explanation, please feel free to ask in the comments :)